# What is the definition of Curl in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, tensors, implementation-details, vector-calculus, operators

I have a usual mathematical background in vector and tensor calculus. I was trying to use the differential operators of Mathematica, namely `Grad`, `Div` and `Curl`. According to my knowledge, the definitions of Mathematica for `Grad` and `Div` coincides with those usually employed in tensor calculus, that is to say

\begin{align*}
\text{grad}\mathbf{T}&:=\sum_{k=1}^{3}\frac{\partial\mathbf{T}}{\partial x_k}\otimes \mathbf{e}_k\\
\text{div}\mathbf{T}&:=\sum_{k=1}^{3}\frac{\partial\mathbf{T}}{\partial x_k}\cdot\mathbf{e}_k \\
\tag{1}
\end{align*}

for any tensor $\mathbf{T}$ of rank $n\ge1$. $x_k$'s are Cartesian coordinates and $\mathbf{e}_i$'s are the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. $\otimes$ and $\cdot$ are the usual generalized outer and inner products which are also defined in Mathematica by `Outer` and `Inner`. The usual definition that I know from tensor calculus for the `Curl` is as follows
\begin{align*}
\text{curl}\mathbf{T}&:=\sum_{k=1}^{3}\mathbf{e}_k\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{T}}{\partial x_k}.
\tag{2}
\end{align*}
However, it turns out that Mathematica's definition for curl is totally different. For example, it returns the `Curl` of a second order tensor as a scalar, while according to $(2)$ it should be a second order tensor.

> I couldn't find a precise definition of Mathematica for `Curl` in the documents. I am wondering what this definition is. What is the motivation for this? and How it can be related to the definition given in $(2)$?

Below is a simple piece of code for you to observe the outputs of Mathematica when we apply the `Grad`, `Div` and `Curl` operators to scalar, vector and second order tensor fields. I would like to draw your attention to some observations. `Curl` of a scalar is returned as a second order tensor, which I don't understand why! `Curl` of a vector coincides with the usual definition of `Curl` used in vector calculus. `Curl` of second order tensor is returned as a scalar, which I don't understand again.

```
Var={Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2],Subscript[x, 3]};
Sca=\[Phi][Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2],Subscript[x, 3]];
Vec={Subscript[v, 1][Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2],Subscript[x, 3]],Subscript[v, 2][Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2],Subscript[x, 3]],Subscript[v, 3][Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2],Subscript[x, 3]]};
Ten=Table[Subscript[T, i,j][Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2],Subscript[x, 3]],{i,1,3},{j,1,3}];
MatrixForm[Grad[Sca, Var]]
MatrixForm[Grad[Vec, Var]]
MatrixForm[Grad[Ten, Var]]
MatrixForm[Div[Sca, Var]]
MatrixForm[Div[Vec, Var]]
MatrixForm[Div[Ten, Var]]
MatrixForm[Curl[Sca, Var]]
MatrixForm[Curl[Vec, Var]]
MatrixForm[Curl[Ten, Var]]
```

I will be happy if someone can reproduce the following result for the curl of a second order tensor with Mathematica's `Curl` function.

\begin{align*}
\text{curl}\mathbf{T}&:=\sum_{k=1}^{3}\mathbf{e}_k\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{T}}{\partial x_k}=\sum_{k=1}^{3}\mathbf{e}_k\times\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{3}T_{ij}\mathbf{e}_i\otimes\mathbf{e}_j\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{3}\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{3}\frac{\partial T_{ij}}{\partial x_k}(\mathbf{e}_k\times\mathbf{e}_i)\otimes\mathbf{e}_j\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{3}\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{3}\sum_{m=1}^{3}\epsilon_{kim}\frac{\partial T_{ij}}{\partial x_k}\mathbf{e}_m\otimes\mathbf{e}_j
\tag{3}
\end{align*}

where $\epsilon_{kim}$ is the `LeviCivitaTensor` for $3$ dimensions. Consequently, we get

\begin{align*}
\left(\text{curl}\mathbf{T}\right)_{mj}=\sum_{k=1}^{3}\sum_{i=1}^{3}\epsilon_{kim}\frac{\partial T_{ij}}{\partial x_k}.
\tag{4}
\end{align*}

Implementing $(4)$ in Mathematica, we obtain

```
CurlTen = Table[
   Sum[
    LeviCivitaTensor[3][[k, i, m]] 
     D[Subscript[T, i, j][Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3]], {Subscript[x, k]}], {k, 1, 3}, {i, 1, 3}],
   {m, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
MatrixForm[CurlTen]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The definition used (motivated by exterior calculus) is as follows:

Given a rectangular array $a$ of depth $n$, with dimensions $\{d, ..., d\}$ (so there are $n$ $d$'s) and a list $x = \{x_1, ..., x_d\}$ of variables, then

```
Curl[a, x] == (-1)^n (n+1) HodgeDual[Grad[a, x], d]
```

If $a$ has depth $n$, then `Grad[a, x]` has depth $n+1$, and therefore `HodgeDual[Grad[a, x], d]` has depth $d-(n+1)$. Clearly then we need $n < d$. Note that $n = 0$ is admitted, i.e. we can take the curl of a scalar function.

In the traditional case of $d=3$ and $n=1$ we have $d-(n+1)=1$ and that's why the curl of a vector is also a vector.

The `HodgeDual` operation starts by antisymmetrizing its first argument, and hence implicitly we really have something like

```
Curl[a, x] == (-1)^n (n+1) HodgeDual[Symmetrize[Grad[a, x], Antisymmetric[All]], d]
```

Finally, one more comment: The definition given assumes that we work with tensors given in components in a Cartesian coordinated and orthonormal basis. If that wasn't the case we would have to insert some additional metric factors. That's handled by the third argument of `Curl` for a variety of alternative coordinate systems.

Comment: (+1) Thank you very much jose. :) Can you also elaborate on what `HodgeDual` does? :)

Comment: HodgeDual is an algebraic operation. It does not contain derivatives. Note for example that Cross of d-1 vectors in dimension d is the HodgeDual of the tensor product of those vectors, modulo a factor (d-1)! due to antisymmetrization. Roughly speaking, HodgeDual takes some directions in space and gives you the orthogonal directions. It's just that rather than giving you lists of vectors, it gives you antisymmetric tensors, the forms of exterior algebra in vector spaces.

Comment: Well, I think that I need to read some math! :D I am not familiar with exterior algebra and cross of many vectors. Do you have any simple reference in mind? :)

Comment: @H.R. The `HodgeDual` or [Hodge star operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator) gives you the complementary subspace that 'completes' the vector space. There is a nice introduction to it (and exterior calculus in general) in Keenan Cranes book [Discrete Differential Geometry: An Applied Introduction](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/DDG/) in chapter four.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke: I am really grateful for your help. :) Many thanks.

Comment: @H.R. You're welcome! :)

Comment: +1 Crystal clear! For readers seeking more math, [here is a related question on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337971/can-the-curl-operator-be-generalized-to-non-3d).

Answer (score 11):

I fail to find a reference for the definition used by `Curl`, but manage to figure out how the `Curl` is defined.

I'll use [Einstein summation convention](http://www.dr-qubit.org/teaching/summation_delta.pdf) for simplicity. The defintion used by `Curl` is summarized as follows:

1. `Curl` of a scalar / zero-order tensor is defined as

$$\text{curl}\  \phi= \epsilon_{kim}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_m}$$

2. `Curl` of a vector / first-order tensor is defined as

$$\text{curl}\  \mathbf{v}= \epsilon_{kim}\frac{\partial v_m}{\partial x_i}$$

3. `Curl` of a matrix / second-order tensor is defined as

$$\text{curl}\  \mathbf{T}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}} \epsilon_{kim}\frac{\partial T_{im}}{\partial x_k}$$

Check

```
ϵ = LeviCivitaTensor[3];

Table[Sum[ϵ[[k, i, m]] D[Sca, Var[[m]]], {m, 3}], {k, 3}, {i, 3}] == 
ϵ.D[Sca, {Var}] == 
TensorContract[ϵ\[TensorProduct]D[Sca, {Var}], {{3, 4}}] == 
Curl[Sca, Var]
(*True*)

Table[Sum[ϵ[[k, i, m]] D[Vec[[m]], Var[[i]]], {m, 3}, {i, 3}], {k, 3}] == 
TensorContract[ϵ\[TensorProduct]D[Vec, {Var}], {{3, 4}, {2, 5}}] == 
Curl[Vec, Var]
(*True*)

1/2 Sum[ϵ[[k, i, m]] D[Ten[[i, m]], Var[[k]]], {k, 3}, {i, 3}, {m, 3}] == 
1/2 TensorContract[ϵ\[TensorProduct]D[Ten, {Var}], {{2, 4}, {3, 5}, {1, 6}}] == 
Curl[Ten, Var]
(*True*)
```

The second question is simple:

```
Table[Sum[ϵ[[k, i, m]] D[Ten[[i, j]], Var[[k]]], {k, 3}, {i, 3}], {m, 3}, {j, 3}] == 
TensorContract[ϵ\[TensorProduct]D[Ten, {Var}], {{2, 4}, {1, 6}}] == 
(Curl[#, Var] & /@ Transpose@Ten // Transpose)
(* True *)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89661/discussion-on-answer-by-xzczd-what-is-the-definition-of-curl-in-mathematica).

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my question, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want improve my answer if possible.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to modify your simple piece of code to make the output more informative. I define a function `dim[]` which is similar to the `Dimensions[]` function but is restricted to matrices and arrays. For example, try `Dimensions[x+y]` which returns `{2}` but `dim[x+y]` returns `0`.

```
ClearAll[dim, id];
dim[x : (_List | _StructuredArray)] := Dimensions@x;
dim[x_Div] = $Failed;
dim[x_] = 0;
id[x_] := (Print[dim[x // Expand]]; x // MatrixForm);

Print["Grad"];
id@Grad[Sca, Var]
id@Grad[Vec, Var]
id@Grad[Ten, Var]
Print["Div"];
id@Div[Sca, Var]
id@Div[Vec, Var]
id@Div[Ten, Var]
Print["Curl"];
id@Curl[Sca, Var]
id@Curl[Vec, Var]
id@Curl[Ten, Var]
```

You wrote

> I couldn't find a precise definition of Mathematica for Curl in the documents

The documentation for `Curl[]` is long and typical of of some of the more obscure Mathematica function documentation. The answer is buried in **Properties & Relations** where it states:

> `Curl[f, {x, y, z}] == (-1)^r (r + 1) HodgeDual[
>      Symmetrize[Grad[f, {x, y, z}], Antisymmetric[All]]]`

but `HodgeDual[]` is even more obscure so I am not surprised that the precise definition is not given. It would be a good idea if it was available to users. So the answer to your first question is that it is still obscure. Even with a definition, one usually tries various examples and examines the results. Sometimes you have to use the function in **not obvious** ways. In any case, if a function does **not** do what you want, you can attempt to write your own function that does exactly what you want. You may decide that this is the better option in your situation.

It is good that you seem to have implemented your own version. I suggest an alternative version and a simple test

```
CurlTen == Transpose@Array[Curl[Ten[[All, #]], Var] &, 3]
```

which returns `True`. I hope this helps you in some small way even though I can't answer your first question.

Answer (score 4):

I am limiting myself to fields defined in the three dimensional Euclidean point space. The curl of a tensor can be found in these simple steps:

1. Take the simple composition of the second-order tensor, `T`, with the `LeviCivitaTensor[3]`. This is effected by the command,

   ```
   Dot[T, LeviCivitaTensor[3]]
   ```
2. Take the transpose of the divergence of the above result using the command:

   ```
   curl[T_] := Transpose[Div[Dot[T, LeviCivitaTensor[3]], {x, y, z}]]
   ```

The result you get here is the second-order tensor that is the curl of the tensor `T`.

Comment: (+1) Hi there, and welcome to this community. :) Have you tested your formula against a tensor of an arbitrary rank `n` and in different curivilinear coordinates such as cylindrical or spherical? Your answer is somehow similar to that of xzczd.

Comment: Thanks for your question.

Comment: To H.R. 
1. Formula tested correctly in Cylindrical and Spherical Polar coordinates using the same example problem in Mathematica 12, transformed to cylindrical and spherical polar coordinates; 
2. Only interested in 3D Euclidean Point Space. 
3. No, this method is different from xzczd. Here, we use transpose of the divergence of the contraction of the tensor argument with the LeviCivitaTensor[3]. I have proved elsewhere that it should give the same result but from different angles except for the scalar multiplier of 1/2.

Comment: @H.R. If I understand it correctly, Fakinlede's answer is just for the 2nd part of the question i.e. "How it can be related to the definition given in $(2)$?" Then I think the first step should be modified to `Dot[Transpose@T, LeviCivitaTensor[3]]`. ( @OAFakinlede Just compare your result to the `CurlTen` in the question. )

Comment: OK, that's fine. But one point I would like to mention is that you can have a tensor of arbitrary rank `n` in a 3D Euclidean space. Indeed, we encounter a lot of such creatures in mathematical physics. :)

Comment: I apologize for my mistake. I misinterpreted your question. I know that you can have tensors of higher orders in 3D Euclidean Point Space. In fact, my present work is about fourth-order and higher-order tensors that appear in constitutive continuum modeling.
I do not know practical uses for curls of tensors of higher orders than two. I have never seen one defined in the scope of my reading and research.
I developed interest in the curl of order two tensors because I thought the definition was rather arbitrary and therefore tried to connect it to better-known constructs.

Comment: @OAFakinlede. As far as I can tell, I didn't edit anything out your post; I only reformatted it. If I inadvertently did edit out something that you feel should be there, by all means edit the question to restore what is missing.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for your response. Don't know who did the editing. Will leave it that way - does not really hurt. My apologies.