# Curl of a scalar in Mathematica

Tags: vector-calculus

What is the reason for Mathematica to produce expressions with opposite signs?

```
Curl[Curl[{X[x, y], Y[x, y], 0}, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]

Curl[Curl[{X[x, y], Y[x, y]}, {x, y}], {x, y}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/191373/12

Comment: Nitpick:  that's not a scalar you're taking the curl of.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert In the second line, s/he's taking the curl of `Curl[{X[x, y], Y[x, y]}, {x, y}]`, which returns a scalar.

Comment: Yes the second line indeed it is the Curl of a scalar. 
It is explained in another post actually and has to do
with Hodge Duality and Exterior Forms.