# Curl in Polar Coordinates

Tags: vector, vector-calculus

I was trying to figure out Curl in other coordinates. The Curl documentation (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curl.html ) didn't really say how Mathematica interpreted the input.

Anyway, I tried the following just to figure it out. {0,x} should have curl of 1 everywhere, where {*,*} is a Cartesian coordinate.

Then, I converted to polar (thinking the answer should still be 1). I found the magnitude r = x and theta = Pi/2 because my vector points in the y direction. Anyway, I ran that and got something funky instead of 1 (see below).

```
Curl[{0,x},{x,y}, "Cartesian"] (*Out[1]= 1*)
Curl[{r Cos[theta],Pi/2},{r,theta},"Polar"] (*Out[2]= -((-(\[Pi]/2)-r Sin[theta])/r)) *)
```

---

### So the question is how does Mathematica interpret curl inputs, why I didn't get 1 as an output, and how to fix that?

I am a beginner so please keep it simple. Links to suitable resources for this are also helpful.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191373)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand too much about tensors.

Comment: Oh wait, it looks like it takes local coordinates as input.

Comment: Try this `TransformedField["Cartesian"->"Polar",{0,x},{x,y}->{r,θ}]//Curl[#,{r,θ},"Polar"]&`.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Should I delete the post?

Comment: @IonSme Great! :) Instead of deleting the post, would you like to make a [self-answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), maybe with some explanation on the "local coordinates" reason you mentioned and why things like `CoordinateTransform` are not applicable here? I think it can be helpful for others.